# will a regular expression applied in reverse produce the same match?

Tags: regex, algorithm

Suppose we have some text and a regular expression that matches it. Question: if I apply the same expression to text backwards (starting from the last letter to the first one), will it still match?

regex -----> text

xereg --?--> txet

In practice that seems to work, the question is rather about what the theory says about the general case.

Comment: I believe that it depends on the expression. Do you have any examples?

Comment: hm, I have examples that proven to work, I am asking about general case

Comment: @bonomo You mean, if you reverse the pattern of the regular expression?

Comment: kind of yes, although you don't need to reverse the pattern itself, what you need is to evaluate the same pattern backwards

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you tring to make a tool for grabing the reversed urls from sharing sites?

Comment: no, I am trying to apply a regex starting from an arbitrary position like with text "http ://google.com" and regexp "http ://google.com" applied starting at "." in both ways will match "com" to the right "elgoog//:ptth" to the left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not if you use the Kleene star - if you reverse the regex, you will end up with an invalid regex or one that matches a different pattern:

- `ab*` -> `*ba` (invalid syntax)
- `a*b` -> `b*a` (the first one matches `aaab` but not `abbb`, while the second one matches `bbba` but not `baaa`)

On the other hand, I'm quite sure that it would be possible to design an algorithm that, given a regex, produces a regex that matches the reverse strings. The following recursive algorithm should work (if *r* is a regex, *rev(r)* means the regex that matches the reversed strings):

- If *r* is a single symbol *x*, then *rev(r) = x*.
- If *r* is a union *A|B*, then *rev(r) = rev(A)|rev(B)*.
- If *r* is a concatenation *AB*, then *rev(r) = rev(B)rev(A)*.
- If *r* is a Kleene star *A**, then *rev(r) = rev(A)**.

Comment: I didn't mean to reverse the expression, the expression is the same, what I meant if we evaluate this expression backwards against reversed text, will it produce the same result.

Comment: @bonomo: I'm not quite following - what exactly do you mean by "evaluating a regular expression backwards"?

Comment: +1, I didn't know I took 8 minutes to type that up. Deleting my response. Edit: Oops--can only vote to delete not actually delete. Well, I'll just leave it there.

Comment: @bonomo: Do you mean that, if the regex is `ab*`, and the string is `abbb`, we should first try to match `b*` against `bbba` (which will consume `bbb`), and then `a` against the remaining `a`?

Comment: @MonsterTruck: Thanks. But I don't think you need to delete yours; you provided some interesting information that I didn't.

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset Eldhuset, I am not sure about the Kleene star pattern in your example. But let's consider a trivial regex "ab?c" you can evaluate it straight a -> b? -> c against "abc" and you can evaluate the same expression backwards c -> b? -> a against "cba" and you will get the same match... Seems like that star operator can ruin the party.

Comment: @bonomo: I'm not comfortable with the notion of "evaluating a regex backwards", since what you are really doing is to construct another regex that matches the reversed strings. As long as `?`, `*`, and `+` are kept on the right hand side of the expression to which they belonged, it will still work. This is essentially what my algorithm does; for instance, `a(bc|d*e)*` would become `(cb|ed*)*a`.

Comment: @bonomo: There is one caveat, though: if you are using capturing groups, you may in some special cases end up with different results: for instance, `(a?)(a*)` applied to `aaa` will yield the match groups `a` and `aa`, while the reverse regex `(a*)(a?)` applied to `aaa` will yield the match grops `aaa` and (empty). However, as long as you are only interested in determining whether a string matches the regex or not, I'm quite sure that the reversal will be safe - `(a?)(a*)` will match the same strings as `(a*)(a?)`.

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset That's right, I don't care much of capturing fragments of text. However what do you think about "." (dot) operator? Can it be reversed?

Comment: @bonomo: Yes; `.` reversed is `.`. For instance, `a(.b)*` matches `acbdbeb`, and the reversed regex `(b.)*a` matches `bebdbca`.

Answer (score 0):

The general cause is that it will not

for example, the regex

```
ab
```

will match

```
ab
```

but not

```
ba
```

How come you think that the general case is that it should?

There are regexes that matches the reverse string as well like

```
[a|b]*
```

Will match

```
ab
```

and

```
ba
```

Comment: if you apply "ab" (a regex) in reverse it will match "ba"

Answer (score 0):

The cases where `regex` and `xeger` would both produce the same match on a text are:

1. `regex` is a simple (atomic) pattern that is a [palindrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome). e.g., `abcba`
2. `regex` is composed of several atomic patterns using [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) functions (e.g., `or`) and you do not reverse those individual atomic patterns. If you do, then they should be a palindrome too. e.g., `adef|bd881|cdavr` if you do not reverse the atomic components or `[aba|defed]` if you do reverse the atomic components.

Answer (score 0):

In general I would definitely say "no", but it really just depends on the complexity of the expressions.

Because not only would one need to reverse any simple (sub-)expressions, but if applicable one would also need to take into account more complex stuff which is not so easily "reversed" in just any regex: what about repetition operators, laziness vs. greediness, or back-references and look-arounds, quantifiers and modifiers… – items explained in e.g. [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)?

Perhaps if you have more specific examples or issues regarding such a "reversal", a more appropriate answer can be thought of.

Comment: I believe we are looking at very basic regex operators: single character, sequence, loop, options, nothing.